# AngularJS: drop-down box binding doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is a simple form which uses AngularJS.

In FireFox (30.0) and IE (11.0.9600.17207), if I choose "Yes, No, No" in drop-down boxed, is shows "true, false, false" as I expect.

In Chrome (36.0.1985.125 m) it shows "true, true, true".

Does anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var testApp = angular.module( 'testApp', [] );

        testApp.controller( 'Ctl1', [
            '$scope',
            function ( $scope ) {

                $scope.questions = [{ id: 1, value: null }, { id: 2, value: null }, { id: 3, value: null }];

                $scope.submit = function () {
                    var results = [];
                    angular.forEach( $scope.questions, function ( v, k ) { results.push( v.value ); } );
                    console.log( results );
                    $scope.results = results;
                }
            }] );

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctl1">

        <h1>Page 1</h1>

        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <p ng-repeat="item in questions">
                <select ng-model="item.value">
                    <option value="true">Yes</option>
                    <option value="false">No</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </form>

        <h1>Page 2</h1>

        <p ng-repeat="item in results track by $index">{{ item }}</p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In `$scope.submit()` it should be `var results = [];` so you aren't adding the variable to the global scope.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/42E4u/ - in Chrome, I get true/false/false (or whatever is exactly chosen)

Comment: The only thing I can see is if it's storing the string "true" and the string "false" and you try to use it in a conditional statement, both are "truthy" and will evaluate to true.

Comment: wired_in - thank you, fixed! But it's still not working as expected.

Comment: @SergeyPopov care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simplify the example and found a workaround.

Here is the simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var testApp = angular.module( 'testApp', [] );

        testApp.controller( 'Ctl1', [
            '$scope',
            function ( $scope ) {
                $scope.value = null;
            }] );

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctl1">

        <p>Value: {{ value }}</p>

        <select ng-model="value">
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the page in Google Chrome
2. Navigate to the drop-down list using keyboard
3. Press "arrow down" twice

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QBjkB/

To fix it I’ve initialized "value" with empty string:

```
function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.value = '';
}
```

And added the option with empty value to a drop-down list:

```
<select ng-model="value">
    <option value="">---</option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

Thank you guys for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at it in a binding sense and it's much easier to see what's going on.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/qgN85/)

```
{{questions}}
```